# How to deserialize xml that has same names in attribute and in property?

Tags: java, xml, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson-dataformat-xml

Jackson throws **jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Conflicting getter definitions for property "NewStatus"** because of same names in attribute and in property.

I tried to change property name during the parsing, using a "crutch" that swaps "NewStatus" on "New_Status", but it causes a lot of different problems.

```
<Test NewStatus="1111111">
    <NewStatus Description="TestDesc"/>
</Test>

@Data
public static class Test {

@JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "NewStatus")
private String newStatusAttribute;

@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "NewStatus")
private NewStatus newStatusTag;

@Data
public static class NewStatus {

@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Description")
private String description;
}
}
```

I want Jackson to parse values from the attribute and from the property.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a known issue. However I tried to generate as per your XML structure. Find below the code. There is a small issue, you can explore more on this.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.xml.annotate.JacksonXmlProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.xml.annotate.JacksonXmlRootElement;

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "NewStatus")
public class NewStatus {
  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
  private String description;

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}


import com.fasterxml.jackson.xml.annotate.JacksonXmlProperty;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore;

public class Test {
  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "NewStatus")
  private String statusAttribute;

  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "NewStatus")
  @JsonIgnore
  private NewStatus newStatus;

  public String getStatusAttribute() {
    return statusAttribute;
  }

  public void setStatusAttribute(String statusAttribute) {
    this.statusAttribute = statusAttribute;
  }

  public NewStatus getNewStatus() {
    return newStatus;
  }

  public void setNewStatus(NewStatus newStatus) {
    this.newStatus = newStatus;
  }
}
```

Test code to verify.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.xml.XmlMapper;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Test1 {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();

    NewStatus newStatus = new NewStatus();
    newStatus.setDescription("TestDesc");

    Test test = new Test();
    test.setNewStatus(newStatus);
    test.setStatusAttribute("1111111");

    String xmlStr = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(test);

    System.out.println(xmlStr);
  }
}
```

The generated xml looks like this.

```
<Test NewStatus="1111111"><newStatus description="TestDesc"/></Test>
```

If you look closely, `<newStatus ...>` is coming differently despite several efforts. This is minor problem. Either you can change the tag name and variable name accordingly.

Besides, I have added the following dependencies in my maven pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-xml-databind</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
            <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

Hope this post may be useful to you.